# Strange behaviour of Subplot in Matplotlib when used by plotfile

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a script for drawing subplots which works perfectly for ploting bars. When I use this script with plotfile function, the outcome is just one plot on top of another. Basically it just shows the second plot. What is the reason for that?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
from operator import add

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,10))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.13, hspace=0.15)

ax1=fig.add_subplot(211)
plt.plotfile('2m_5m_stringsearch', delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1), color='green', linewidth= 1.5, linestyle='-.',dashes=(5,8), marker='', label='stringsearch')
plt.ylim(0,1)
ax1.set_xticklabels([])
plt.ylabel('SER of Leon3-C1')

ax2=fig.add_subplot(212)
plt.plotfile('2m_5m_stringsearch', delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1), color='green', linewidth= 1.5, linestyle='-.',dashes=(5,8), marker='', label='stringsearch')
plt.ylim(0,1)
ax2.set_xticklabels([])
plt.ylabel('SER of Leon3-C2')

plt.savefig("Output.pdf", dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.05)
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, have you found an answer by any chance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the content of the `pyplot.py` package, I realised that the `plotfile` function did not interface well with subplots: if you want to plot multiple columns of a file to subplots, it can easily do that.

If you want to arbitrarily plot multiple (potentially different) files to different subplots, then it can't.

The solution I found was to use `numpy` `genfromtxt` to read the data myself by writing our own `plot_file` function:

```
import numpy as np
def plot_file(ax, fnme, cols=[], label=None):
    data = np.genfromtxt(
      fnme,
      skip_header=0,
      skip_footer=0,
      names=[str(col) for col in cols],
    )
    ax.plot(*[data[str(col)] for col in cols], label=label)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3))
PLOT_INDEXES = range(0,2)
for i in PLOT_INDEXES:
    ax = plt.subplot(1, len(PLOT_INDEXES), i+1)
    plot_file(ax, 'test_{0}.txt'.format(i), cols=[0, 1], label=str(i))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be because of [this from the docs about the `newfig` argument](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plotfile):

> If newfig is True, the plot always will be made in a new figure; if
>   False, it will be made in the current figure if one exists, else in a
>   new figure.

`newfig` defaults to `True`. Try passing `newfig=False` to `pylab.plotfile`.

Comment: I am having the same problem, while already calling `plotfile` with `newfig=False`. Any other ideas ?